# Express.js req.body.length giving undefined inside controller

Tags: javascript

**controller page**

this is the controller page where request body is coming

```
exports.sellerregistration = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.length)//undefined
};
```

**server page**

this is the server page

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: Can you please provide bit more details like request data and the header details, If it is straight forward API request with JSON data then it should work.

Comment: `length` works on arrays, while `req.body` is an object try to `console.log(req.body)` you will get the complete object. If your request body contain length as key value pair then ultimately you will get that property using `req.body.length`. Can you please show us what you are passing in req body?

Comment: i am sending JSON object like `{"name": "ritesh kumar thakur", age: 23}` and i want to get length of this object which is 2 right now

Comment: @Sheri  `{
    "id": "789",
    "type": "buyer",
    "invoiceStatus": "Pending"
}` this is what i am trying to send

Comment: One solution i found was `Object.keys(req.body).length`

Comment: yes this is the right way to go `Object.keys(req.body).length`

Comment: @Sheri i used to do `req.body.length` before but now it's now working why

Comment: `req.body.length` its not work at all as i told you in my recent comments. until and unless your req body contains length property as key value.